# Animate a property, but not in older Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a website that needs to be compatible with IE7+.
Animating some CSS properties is painfully slow on IE7 and IE8, while it's perfectly fine on other browsers.

Thus, I'd like to use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) on fast browsers, and [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) on older browsers.

I wanted to use [$.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) for this, but it's been deprecated in jQuery 1.9.
The documentation advises to use feature detection instead ([$.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/)), but that's not what I want (unless there's some kind of "fast browser" or "modern browser" feature...)

What's a good way to detect a "slow" browser (understand: IE7/IE8) nowadays, **using jQuery if possible**?

Comment: You could use a [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Recent versions of Internet Explorer do not support them anymore, but IE7/8 do.

Comment: That's would have been my best bet, but it does not integrate well with my code (this is an external .js file, thus a JS-only solution is preferred).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the standard javascript `navigator.userAgent` object detection method so for example,

e.g.

```
var ieVersion = new Number(RegExp.$1);
if ((/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) && (ieVersion < 9)){
    //Perform CSS function for IE8 and lower
    alert('IE8-');
}
else
{
    //Perform animate function for everything else
    alert('Everything else');
}
```

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6wT9/2/) of the above.

Comment: I was hoping that jQuery provided a "cleaner" way to do this (such as just testing a `$.something` object, but it probably doesn't anymore. Anyway, I've actually realized since that the animation is not the biggest problem, using `.css()` does not make it much faster as it still struggles to redraw the content in a timely fashion.

Comment: Yeah I miss the `$.browser` function too, anyway I hope it helped.